# iPhone 6s and 6s+ font size and image size

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

Guys I'm facing a issue in 6s & 6s+ device... Can anyone help me with it.. I'm using auto layouts and storyboard

I'm using custom font for the entire app called San Francisco and these fonts looks good with iPhone 5s with perfect size that I'm setting in story board but in 6s and 6s+ some how it's coming in small size !

And even the images are slightly small in size ! I am having 3 sizes like (1x, 2x, 3x) that is also coming small in 6s device ! Let me give you an example like when I use a button with a image ! In story board I have a view controller of size 320 x 568. And I'm setting auto layout in that view controller and when I give image to that button ! That image appears to be small in the 6s & 6s+ device how to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Assets` to set images. And you should add image for all resolution like `1x,2x,3x`. For example your image size is `24x24` for 1x then your 2x image should be `48x48` and 3x should be `72x72`. your `6+` will use `3x` resolution and all other devices will use `2x`. If you are not giving support to older `ios` versions or devices then you can skip `1x` image, But if your app support ipads also then you need `1x` and `2x`.

You can refer [Asset Catalog Help - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html).

Second thing you can use `size classes` for different size of your views and your fonts according to different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the immediate reply. But I'm using Assets to set images. Inspite of that im getting this issue

Comment: then your image size is small compare to your `UI` or you are setting wrong constraints.

Comment: Edit your question with your setup then anybody can help not only me!